# AMP font-face not working

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, amp-html

I am currently stuck on my AMP site. I have a CSS file just for my AMP site and i set the font-face below for it.
I have to use the something like this because I **need** to access those font-files from my assets folder.

I am using Rails 5

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src:font-url('poppins-v5-latin-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: local('Poppins Regular'), local('Poppins-Regular'),
    font-url('poppins-v5-latin-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
    font-url('poppins-v5-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
    font-url('poppins-v5-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
    font-url('poppins-v5-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
    font-url('poppins-v5-latin-regular.svg#Poppins') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
/* poppins-700 - latin */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    src:font-url('poppins-v5-latin-700.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: local('Poppins Bold'), local('Poppins-Bold'),
    font-url('poppins-v5-latin-700.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
    font-url('poppins-v5-latin-700.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
    font-url('poppins-v5-latin-700.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
    font-url('poppins-v5-latin-700.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
    font-url('poppins-v5-latin-700.svg#Poppins') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Fonts included via @font-face must be fetched via the HTTP or HTTPS scheme.
Source: https://www.ampproject.org/docs/design/responsive/custom_fonts

Answer (score 0):

Via @font-face (no restrictions, all fonts allowed), You should use the full path.

Eg: http://somedomain.org/VeraSeBd.ttf or https://somedomain.org/VeraSeBd.ttf

```
<style amp-custom>
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Bitstream Vera Serif Bold";
    src: url("https://somedomain.org/VeraSeBd.ttf");
  }

  body {
    font-family: "Bitstream Vera Serif Bold", serif;
  }
</style>
```

> Fonts included via @font-face must be fetched via the HTTP or HTTPS scheme.

Comment: Share your font for check

Comment: I already did. I am using Rails and I need to use fonts via font-face that are in my assets/fonts because of the GDPR..